# What does _mingw.h header file do?

Tags: c++, mingw, header-files, mingw-w64, mingw32

While I was solving a program in C++, I came across this library _mingw.h, and got curious as to what its use is. From the name I guessed it has something to do with the compiler.

Comment: Looks like it defines a few compiler and windows related defines. [https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/crt/_mingw.h.in](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/crt/_mingw.h.in)

Comment: @drescherjm By compatibility defines do you mean 32bit and 64bit?I opened the github link you provided but I am not too well versed it C++, will be glad if you can elaborate .Thank you :).

Comment: Just read the file I linked Its not that hard to read. With that said I am not sure why you are so interested in this file. It won't fix any problem in your code or anything.

Comment: @drescherjm Ya I just read it, it contains compatibility for 64bit. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

> What does _mingw.h header file do?

In general, it does same thing that all headers do. Headers contain declarations.

Judging by the name, it might be part of the MinGW project. More accurate guess requires context about where you found that header. Regardless, including it would likely make your program dependent on using that specific toolchain.

Note that if the header is undocumented, then you should not rely on the anything declared within it because there won't be any guarantee that the header would remain the same across different versions. Nor should you rely on the file existing. Therefore it will be quite rare for it to be useful to know what is declared in such header. Nevertheless, you can open the file to find out what it declares.